# Codeigniter get one column with this->db->like()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to do a search in a table with LIKE utility.There are 8 column in the table but i need one of them. So that I should get one column. How can i do that with codeigniter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want one column returned, you would use:

```
$this->db->select('column_name');
```

Before using your like() statement.